# Form validation rules not successful

Tags: php, codeigniter

For some reason when I run the submit function it returns an error that tells me the form did not submit properly but while looking over the docs I was not able to find out how to display what rules were not validated correctly.

```
{"output_status":"Error","output_title":"Form Not Validated","output_message":"The form did not validate successfully!"}
```

This is my controller code:

```
public function form_is_valid()
{
    /* Set validation rules for post data */
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean|min_length[6]|max_length[12]|regex_match[/[a-z0-9]/]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|min_length[6]|max_length[12]|regex_match[/[a-z0-9]/]'); 
    //$this->form_validation->set_rules('remember', 'Remember Me', 'trim|xss_clean|integer');

    /* Form validation passed */
    return $this->form_validation->run();
}

public function submit()
{
    if (!$this->form_is_valid())
    {
        $this->output('The form did not validate successfully!', 'Form Not Validated', 'Error');
        return;
     }

     ... rest of submit function code...
}
```

The posted values are:

```
password    testpass
username    testuser
```

Comment: This is just a set of function calls. We need to see the validation code as well as the values you are passing. It's most likely a problem with your input.

Comment: The validation code is in the rules that are set above but I will update the post with the submitted values.

Comment: What does `echo validation_errors();` show?

Comment: I've never seen that function before? Where is that located at?

Comment: Oh I see that in the helper at the bottom. I bypassed it but how should I work that in?

Comment: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#errordelimiters

Comment: You can either add it just before the return statement in `submit()`, or cat it on to the end of the error string.

Comment: If you've figured out what the problem is, you can post it as an answer yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to with the comments in this question thread use the  function with use of the user guide on the codeigniter website. And find out that I was forgetting the username had to be atleast 6 characters long.